# HDFS namenote fails while copying files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

If I am copying a file in HDFS, and while copying of file NameNode goes down.

What happens next, Are we not able to copy the file further and the process is rollback.

Or the file gets copied, if this happens then How Hadoop manage this process??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While copying, each file is copied as group of independent block ,if all the block of file is copied then only the client is notified otherwise the process fails

say you are copying abc.txt which is of 100mb so it is copied in term of block (default 64 mb) ,for every block the client connects namenode and obtain the adrress of datanode for actually storing the block so suppose 1 block is getting copied and namenode goes down then at the 2nd block when client again connects to datanode for obatining address it will get an error

failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused